# ppx_traverse_builtins failed

Tags: node

While upgrading the node using `make build-deps` I've got the following error indication related to **ppx_traverse_builtins**. 
Node was successfully compiled though.

Does anybody know about **ppx_traverse_builtins** ? Is it safe to run the node having this error?

Any suggestions are welcome.

```
[ERROR] The compilation of ppx_traverse_builtins failed at "/home/ubuntu/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build jbuilder build -p  -j 1".


=== ERROR while compiling ppx_traverse_builtins.v0.10.0 ======================#
 context     2.0.0 | linux/x86_64 | ocaml-base-compiler.4.06.1 | no repo
 path        ~/tezos/_opam/.opam-switch/build/ppx_traverse_builtins.v0.10.0
 command     ~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build jbuilder build -p  -j 1
 exit-code   1
 env-file    ~/.opam/log/ppx_traverse_builtins-18359-22ffbe.env
 output-file ~/.opam/log/ppx_traverse_builtins-18359-22ffbe.out
 output ###
 Error: I don't know about package  (passed through --only-packages/--release)



<><> Error report <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build ppx_traverse_builtins v0.10.0
```

Comment: I've got the same problem.

Comment: if you will even know how to solve it, or what caused it, shoot a message here please. ! Thanks. For now I just left it as is and it is working normally.

Comment: Yeah, my node is in perfect shape, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly safe to run a node without `ppx_traverse_builtins`.

`ppx_traverse_builtins` used to be a dependency of a dependency of tezos software that we never used directly. (Moreover it is a compile time preprocessor, not something you ever need at runtime)

At some point, we updated the dependency that depended on `ppx_traverse_builtins`, removing completely the need for it. Now, on fresh source compilation, it is not installed at all anymore. On update, as it used to be here, it is less smooth and you end up in situation where opam says "I tried and failed to recompile `ppx_traverse_builtins` so I removed it" but "Yes, OK, fine, we don't care about `ppx_traverse_builtins` :-)"